# Ubuntu freezing irregularly for unknown reason

Tags: 20.04, thinkpad, bug-reporting

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop (Focal Fossa). I installed it recently and it's a clean installation.

When it happens, everything stops, even the cursor, but sometimes i still am able to move it slowly. I'd manage to reset the device using the MagicSysRqKey.

I use chrome, but i already disabled the hardware acceleration and the gpu rasterization. I also updated the BIOS with the official release for my computer. This did help but it still happens some times.

---

Here are the specs of my device:

```
Lenovo Thinkpad 440
Memory: 3.7 GiB
Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-4300U CPU @ 1.90GHz × 4 
Graphics: Intel® HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2)
Os Type: 64-bit
GNOME Version: 3.36.2

SMBIOS 2.7 present.
61 structures occupying 2457 bytes.
```

---

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          3.7Gi       1.1Gi       1.1Gi       116Mi       1.5Gi       2.3Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi

$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60

$ grep -i swap /etc/fstab
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

[image: top]

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and a screenshot of `top`.

Comment: Sure. Now i added what you asked me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only 4G RAM, and 2G swap, it leads me to think that you've got a swap problem. We'll increase the /swapfile from 2G to 4G.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 4G RAM and 4G swap
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Comment: This solved the problem! Thank you for you answer.

Comment: @Kyostenas Thanks for the update! Glad it worked for you!